# How to make horizontal strips across full screen without this "hack"

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I'm building a theme for a site and the behavior I want is for the main content to be contained in a horizontally centered `div` with a `max-width`, except for occasional rows that have colored backgrounds extending the entire width of the screen (this is the type of look that a lot of modern sites have). I'm also using bootstrap and I don't know if there are classes built-in for me to do this type of thing. But what I've been doing is like

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <p>Here's a row that stays contained in the container</p>
   </div>
   <div class="row expand-full-width">
       <div class="container">
           <p>Here's a row that is contained in the center but has a background extended all the way across the screen horizontally</p>          
       </div>
   </div/>
   <div class="row">
       <p>Here's a row that stays contained in the container</p>
   </div>
   <div class="row expand-full-width">
       <div class="container">
           <p>Here's a row that is contained in the center but has a background extended all the way across the screen horizontally</p>          
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.container { width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .row { padding: 15px 5px; }
    .expand-full-width { margin-left: -1000000px; margin-right: -1000000px; background:  yellow; }
```

---

(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjpuLcat/)

but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it because the `margin-left: -somebignumber; margin-right: -somebignumber;` "hack" is messing up the structure of some 3rd-party items I'm trying to incorporate in my site, including a JavaScript carousel. So is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely right to think that having huge negative margins is not a great idea. Instead of having one `.container` that wraps everything, you should have `.container`s within each section.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Here's a row that stays contained in the container</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row expand-full-width">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Here's a row that is contained in the center but has a background extended all the way across the screen horizontally</p>          
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Here's a row that stays contained in the container</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row expand-full-width">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Here's a row that is contained in the center but has a background extended all the way across the screen horizontally</p>          
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.container { width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .row { padding: 15px 5px; }
    .expand-full-width { background:  yellow; }
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6384cow/)